# Failed to access the WSDL from Eclipse client application. expected {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions found link

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to run java client application from Eclipse. 
I created client stubs from a wsdl.

Getting below error on run.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL. 
It failed with:     Invalid WSDL , expected {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions found link

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:225)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:163)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:306)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:215)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:192)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
```